Canvas animation on scroll show rest of website at canvas end
I am using this tutorial to show a animation when the user scrolls. This is working perfectly.
The problem I am facing now, is that I have no clue how to show the rest of the website when someone reaches the end of the animation.
What I would like to achieve is this:

User scrolls to the end of the animation.
Animation has reached the end, the cavas is moving to the top i.e. normal scrolling behaviour.
The rest of the website is shown as it normally would.
If the user scrolls back up, the canvas will re-appear and display the animation in reverse order.

Can someone please explain to me, how I can make the canvas move up when the user keeps scrolling down at the end of the animation, so I can show the rest of the website?
Obvious, vice versa when the user scrolls back up.
My example code is the exact same as in the tutorial.
I searched on the internet for things like "Move canvas at animation end" but I was unable to find a working example.
Check this page, you can see that the canvas moves when you reach the end of the animation, and then the rest of the website is displayed: https://www.apple.com/macbook-air/
<canvas id="hero-lightpass"></canvas>

<div style="background: red; width: 100%; padding: 48px; display: block; margin-bottom: 24px; margin-top: 38000px;">
    Here is some info<br /> Here is some info<br /> Here is some info<br /> Here is some info<br /> Here is some info<br /> Here is some info<br />
    Here is some info<br /> Here is some info<br /> Here is some info<br /> Here is some info<br /> Here is some info<br /> Here is some info<br />
    Here is some info<br /> Here is some info<br /> Here is some info<br /> Here is some info<br /> Here is some info<br /> Here is some info<br />
    Here is some info<br /> Here is some info<br /> Here is some info<br /> Here is some info<br /> Here is some info<br /> Here is some info<br />
</div>

A working example can be found here:
https://codepen.io/Digital-Forge/pen/LYwRmNG
So: When the RED area comes into screen, it should push up the canvas. And when you scroll back up, the canvas should flow into position again and remain there for the animation (in reverse).

Runnable code should be in the question it self as a [mcve].
